# Get dropdown values using actions class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

After moving to the value which is present in dropdown, i want to get it using actions class. Below is the code i have written. i am trying to print the dropdown values. HTML tag for dropdown is input(for select i have code). Please help me

```
public static void caseSearch()
{
    try
    {
        Actions a=new Actions(driver);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.info("clicking on cases tab :: ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(loader.getProperty(Constants.CaseTab))).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(loader.getProperty(Constants.CaseSearch)));
        ele.click();
        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
        {
            //i want to print the first value of dropdown in console
            a.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN,Keys.DOWN,Keys.DOWN).build().perform();
            String value=ele.getText();
            System.out.println("value is = "+value);
            a.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN,Keys.DOWN).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.info("case search method is not executed  :: " +e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you need to get all the available options is a drop down with select/options tab?

Comment: yes exactly. but the tag is Input.

Comment: What is the err msg or output you are getting for your code?

Comment: actually it is printing null values instead of dropdown values. that is the issue. no error was throwing

Comment: Can i have the site url and details?

Comment: i am working for project and we are using local url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150796/discussion-between-santhosh-kumar-and-potnuru-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to get the value from the dropdown box.
You need to use the Select Class to get it.

```
Actions key = new Actions(browser);
```

WebElement dropdownElement = this.browser.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR DROPDOWN ELEMENT"));

```
      Select dropOptions = new Select(dropdownElement);
      int elements = dropOptions.getOptions().size();

      for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
           dropdownElement.click();
           if (i > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                key.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).build().perform();
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                key.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
           }
           else {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                ActionPerformers.sendActionKey(browser, Keys.ENTER);
           }
           System.out.println("ELEMENT " + i + " -> " + dropOptions.getFirstSelectedOption().getText()); //Here you will get the selected Value...
      }
```

This is only an exemple, I hope it suits you.